# How to break a loop when the user types "quit"?

Tags: c, string

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  char str[100];
  int i;
  for(;;){
    printf( "Enter a value :");
    scanf("%s %d", str, &i);
    if (str == "quit") break;
    printf( "You entered: %s %d\n ", str, i);
  }
}
```

I'm trying to ask the user to write characters and integers, then output these values.
My problem is: how to break the loop whenever the user types `quit` or `exit` ?

Correct Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
char str[100];
int i;
for(;;) {
printf( "Enter a value :");
scanf("%s %d", str, &i);
if (strcmp(str,"quit") == 0 || strcmp(str,"exit") == 0) break;
printf( "You entered: %s %d\n ", str, i);
}
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
if (str == "quit") break;
```

The condition `str == "quit"` is the part that has a problem. It would compare the pointers which would never be the same, you should use `strcmp` to compare strings instead:

```
if (strcmp(str, "quit") == 0) break;
```

Answer (score 2):

you should use strcmp to compare a string !

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    char str[100];
    int i;
    for(;;) {
        printf( "Enter a value :");
        scanf("%s %d", str, &i);
        if (strcmp(str,"quit") == 0) break;
        printf( "You entered: %s %d\n ", str, i);        
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `strcmp` or `strncmp` (in `<string.h>`) to compare two `char *`

```
if (strncmp(str, "quit", 4) == 0) break;
```

Comment: `strncmp` is not necessary over `strcmp` here because `strlen("quit")` is well-defined to be 4.

Comment: `strncmp` has another problem here: what if the user types `quitisnotwhatiwant`?

Answer (score -1):

You can't compare string with operator "==" cause the compiler will not get how compare character. You'll have to use function for that (or your own if you want) ==> Strcmp which will compare each char of the string.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
  #include <string.h>
     int main(void)
    {
    char str[100];
    int i;
    for(;;){
    printf( "Enter a value :");
    scanf("%s %d", str, &i);
    if (strcmp(str,"quit") == 0 || strcmp(str,"exit") == 0) break;

    printf( "You entered: %s %d\n ", str, i);

    }
    return (0):
    }
```

Comment: Make sure to explain what changes were done and why.